# PHP: Simple regular expressions to match length?

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match

I'm creating a registration system that needs to check the name/pass etc. with REGEX (and prefer to), what I've got so far is:

```
//Check so numbers aren't first, such as 00foobar
preg_match('/^(?!\d)[a-z0-9]+$/iD',$usrname);
//Just simple check
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$psword);
```

But I have to do stupid things in IF statements like:

`if strlen($psword) > 30 || if (strlen($psword) < 4) ....`

How would I impliment the length checking in my two original regular expression statements? This would make me so happy..

Comment: I don't think the `if` is stupid at all. It's perfectly readable; you don't have to do everything in a single regex. Either way, *please* allow more characters than that in passwords. As someone who likes using properly secure passwords with a wide range of punctuation in, there's nothing more frustrating than a site that needlessly limits passwords to alphanumerics.

Comment: @bobince 30 just sounded like a good enough number, a "big one", I'm working on a project with someone, so I will add it higher and explain.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

same but using the \w and \d for word and digits, but you might want also to include basic symbols like `%!?/ ... etc...`

```
preg_match('/^[\w\d]{4,30}$/',$psword);
```

the `{n,v}` would validate for minimum n and maximum v elements before.

like `A{2,3}` would validate for `AA` and `AAA`. you can take a look [there](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for more references

On the same fashion if you want only to set the minimum of patern `{n,}` would do it. For example:

```
preg_match('/^[\w\d]{4,}$/',$psword);
```

Comment: If you do set how large a password can be, I'd suggest more than 30 characters. Some people have long passwords, and good for them. Its more secure.

Comment: Given, that this is 30 characters: `thisais30characterspasswordyay`. I know one of my passwords is longer than that.

Comment: @Charchar102, You're right, but this is for a simple game so I'll just maybe keep it to 40.

Comment: "On the same fashion if you want only to set the minimum of patern {n} would do it." That should be {n,} if minimum only.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should do the trick:

> preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,30}$/',$psword);